# Display problem when adjusting brightness in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, display, brightness

Recently I installed **Ubuntu 12.04** on my **Dell 1554** laptop.

I was **adjusting** my **screen brightness** when this happened :

[image: http://picpaste.com/vlcsnap-2012-12-12-11h00m07s235-XPRzNM9G.png]

this has become a *recurring* problem which is really annoying.

I also want to tell you that :

1. **I have installed the graphics drivers ATI/AMD FGLRX graphics driver.**
2. **I have got my graphics driver checked by Dell.**

Can anybody tell me a *solution* to this and moreover *is anybody out there who is having the same problem*?

Thanks in advance.

*H/W and S/w details:*

> Dell Studio 1554 Processor : Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 430 @ 2.27GHz × 4
>
> Memory : 4 GB
>  VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro
> Devices [AMD] nee ATI Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series]
>
> OS : Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
> Kernel: Linux 3.2.0-34-generic

Comment: Well, your video card somehow switched to console mode. If it doesn't happen in Windows, it's certainly a driver bug (or an Ubuntu bug -- try updating to 14.04 or at least a kernel in the 3.5.0 series). Also this might be due to the "age" of the video card -- how old is it? (if the problem also appears in Windows). Try not tweaking the brightness though from the driver; use the physical controls on your display (if there are any) -- I am unable to use software controls since I upgraded to the last version of Windows...

Comment: This has some connection to new amd drivers. I had similar problem with radeon 5470. I sold the laptop before I had time to solve it.

Comment: Is your system having an Intel graphics card as well(Hybrid)?

Comment: Updating to 14.04 is not a good solution. But installing `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` and `xserver-xorg-lts-trusty` packages on 12.04 may help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're adjusting the brightness, but using `xrandr`, may yield different results.

As in `xrandr --output VGA-0 --brightness 1.1` or `0.8` for darker, etc (see `xrandr`'s output for your output name, maybe HDMI-0 or so)

[Q showed up in "Unanswered Questions", may help someone with a different brightness option. Probably will never get a reply from @Maverick Snyder though, last seen in 2013]